Does metal roofing need to extend past the drip edge?
Does metal roofing need to extend past the drip edge on a 4/12 roof?

Many roofs extend 3 feet past the wall - save water splash...

This depends on what is below it.

What angle is the roof? What is below it? Prevailing wind direction and strength?

Yes, at least 1" is what I would recommend.
It could be less, but the idea is so that wind driven weather will not push the snow/rain so readily between the roofing and the drip edge. You should also be using the foam rubber filler strips if the roofing is different than the standing seam roofing.


Both images courtesy Home Depot
